# why here it is not aligned in a single row as i have given them equally 6 column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gridview

The Bootstrap grid columns I have used have resulted in overlapping content instead of proper horizontal alignment. Here's the HTML code I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/55fbb5a005.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container-fluid ">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 p-3">
               <img src="https://d1tgh8fmlzexmh.cloudfront.net/ccbp-responsive-website/ecommerce-trending-blogs-1-img.png" class="keyboard">
               <div class="shadow p-3 box-1">
                  <h5 class="sub-head">Fountain Pens</h5>
                  <h2 class="head">Guide to Fountain Pen Nibs</h2>
                  <p class="para">If you're having trouble with a fountain pen, whether it is scratchy, too dry, or too wet...</p>
                  <p><span class="change">Read More <i class="fa-sharp fa-regular fa-arrow-right"></i></span></p>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 p-3">
               <img src="https://d1tgh8fmlzexmh.cloudfront.net/ccbp-responsive-website/ecommerce-trending-blogs-2-img.png" class="keyboard">
               <div class="shadow p-3 box-1">
                  <h5 class="sub-head">Productivity</h5>
                  <h2 class="head">How to Craft a Better Todo List</h2>
                  <p class="para">A well-crafted todo list acts as a guiding light for your day. It helps you overcome...</p>
                  <p><span class="change">Read More <i class="fa-sharp fa-regular fa-arrow-right"></i></span></p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Note that I have used 6 columns for each row within the grid, but it did not align horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Set **col-12 md-6 p-3**  to  **col-12 col-md-2 p-3**

```html
  <div class="col-12 col-md-2 p-3">
```

Hope So it will work